# Remote debugging suddenly stopped working, and troubleshooting yields no clear culprit where the problem could be

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

My remote debugger suddenly stopped working.  This morning, it worked fine.  This afternoon, I can't use it, and neither can at least 2 other members of my team nor can our build server which hasn't been updated, making a total of 4 systems, none of which have the same histories.  2 of the systems have .NET 5 SDK, two have .NET 6.  3 of the systems are running the latest code and 1 is running older code (we're regressing as I write this, no changes so far).  Visual studio 2022 (17.2.0) doesn't give an error, just seems to attach without actually functioning (I can even terminate the process it is "attached" to without repercussion)- it still looks like it's attached, and nothing, not even debug messages or symbol loads, appears in the Output-Debug window.   VS 2019 (16.11.14) simply fails with an error message saying "One or more errors occurred.  Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.  The operation was canceled."  At least it fails, but there's nothing in the output window to say why.
There are 3 separate devices we're trying to debug, on 2 different networks.  All are exhibiting the same problem.  I don't expect easy answers here, but if you could give me an idea what I should try to troubleshoot next I'd appreciate it.

To sum up:
4 different systems, 3 different modules, 3 different revisions of code, 2 different networks, 2 different versions of visual studio.  All exhibiting the same problem.  If we could narrow it down to a single issue, that would make a big difference.  Any ideas?

Comment: Has your I.T. department messed something up for you?

Comment: @MatthewWatson They are gone for the weekend, but I doubt it- and as I said this is happening across 2 different networks (3 if you count a vpn).

Comment: So we are using VS Code with C# and docker containers doing remote debugging and yesterday after upgrading vs code ours stopped working for some strange reason.  Literally it was working fine, one of my team mates said he was having issues, I thought, let me upgrade vs code to see if I can get the same error.  I did and got the error, did not change anything in code.  Now I cant get rid of it.  Tried downgrading vs code, created a new project and still have it.  At a complete loss.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Confirmed no, IT didn't do anything to us Friday.

Answer (score 2):

So this might be a long shot but it worked for our issue.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling the vsdbg (Remote Debugging).

Our setup is VSCode with C# debugging inside docker containers.  My team mate was using Mac, I was using Windows WSL2.  After an upgrade to VSCode both our setups quit working, we were no longer able to debug.  Everything built fine and the containers would run like normal but only fail when you attempted to debug.  The culprit turned out to be vsdbg.  The solution was to uninstall/delete and let VSCode reinstall it on the first attempt to debug again.

Comment: Good thought, but many of us don't have VS Code and so I don't believe we have vsdbg installed.

Comment: @Raligan my team mate on the Mac had two folders: vsdbg for Visual Studio and .vsdbg for VS Code.  He had the issue on both and fixed it by deleting them.  It might be worth a look to see if you have one your machines and rename it and see what happens.

Comment: I took a couple of days off and when I came back everything worked again.  It takes a lot longer to launch the debug adapter, but it works again.  No changes took place on the underlying systems while I was away.  Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I noticed that too but I thought it was just my machine.  Well, glad it is working again now.

Comment: Just another observation, I have found that if I run my code using WSL2 and debug docker containers it does not take a long time to start but if I run on windows it does.  So it might be worth a try to setup your project on WSL2 and see if you can get the speed back.